# Rails: Save and Shift to next tab Backend functionality

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to Implement functionality with code as shown in link below, But Instead of "Next" and "Previous", I am putting "Save" and "Next". When I click on "Save" - without the page getting refreshed, I should be able to navigate to next tab by saving data to backend (Rails).

1 Method of doing it is "Ajax", But I don't know How to start with it.

[CODE LINK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/R3mCY/50/)

```
// Code in js-fiddle
```

Comment: When the 'Save' button is clicked trigger an ajax call to the backend, and on success make the tab proceed to the next. Here's a link to write an ajax method in jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

try below code to click on save button, run ajax, save data and then show next tab:

```
$(".save_btn").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/path",
    data: "params1=data",
    success: function(){
      $("#tab2").show();
    }

  })
})
```